# how to change the status bar color of datepicker?

Tags: android

I have a data picker:

```
 val builder = MaterialDatePicker.Builder.dateRangePicker()
        val picker = builder.build()
        picker.show(childFragmentManager, picker.toString())
```

and it's status bar color black:

[image]

I want it to be transparent like in fragment which hosts this DataPicker:

[image]

how to do it?

Comment: There is an open issue on github: https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/966

Answer (score 4):

After some in-depth research of the theming of the material date picker, I was able to figure it out:

In your activity theme you have to add

```
<item name="materialCalendarFullscreenTheme">@style/CustomMaterialCalendarFullscreenTheme</item>
```

And create the theme the following way

```
<style name="CustomMaterialCalendarFullscreenTheme" parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialCalendar.Fullscreen">
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
</style>
```

You could add a custom status bar color by adding this to the `CustomMaterialCalendarFullscreenTheme`:

```
<item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/someCoolColor</item>
```

**Note:** If you are not interested in what caused the problem you could stop reading here!

The reason is that one of the ancestors of `ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialCalendar.Fullscreen` has `android:windowIsFloating` set to `true` and if the 'floating' content is very big (as in our case, it is fullscreen) Android decides to change the status bar color to black.